# Owner's photo in the pull down menu

Tags: contacts, 4.1-jelly-bean, notification-bar

In 4.2.2, how can I put a picture in the pull down menu like this?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the People application (it's the name of the contacts app in Jelly Bean) and edit the entry for "Me". Set your picture there.

Comment: When I select a picture, it just ignores it. Any clue what type/size it has to be  to work?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the man picture on the drop down. Click on the man picture on the next two screens that come up. You should have two options "Take new photo" and "Select new photo from Gallery", add the photo here.

Comment: This procedure won't always work: because of a change in JB 4.2, some 4.2 ROMs have a bug where, when you click on the default contact icon in the quick tray, it displays a toast **Contact not found** instead of letting you edit the contact. If that happens, you have to go through **People** as Tim describes.

Comment: @DanHulme Ah, I only tried it on stock. Which (popular) ROMs do this?

Comment: The stock Nexus 7 ROM for 4.2.2 (build JDQ39) does it, for instance.

Comment: @DanHulme I have that and this method works fine on it. Have you heard this from other sources or just tried it on your device?

Comment: @Peanut I've seen it on several devices.